# how to loop JSON object using ngFor in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7

loop the object list getting from json object

this is my json object i am getting

```
 {
  "0": {
    "0": null,
    "1": "Consolidated Statements of Changes in Stockholders\u2019 Deficit",
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "",
    "6": "Balance at September 30, 2013",
    "7": "",
    "8": "Common stock issued for exercise of options",
    "9": "Common stock issued for services",
    "10": "Common stock issued to employees",
    "11": "Common stock returned by employees",
    "12": "Net loss for the nine months",
    "13": "Shares issued as finance fee",
    "14": "Amortization of deferred compensation",
    "15": "Common stock issued for acquisition",
    "16": "Payment on convertible note",
    "17": "Exercise of common stock warrants",
    "18": "Unrealized loss on securities, net",
    "19": "Preferred stock",
    "20": "Balance at June 30, 2014",
    "21": "",
    "22": "Net loss for the year",
    "23": "Amortization of deferred compensation",
    "24": "Shares issued for conversion of notes payable",
    "25": "Write-off of derivative liability upon conversion",
    "26": "Unrealized loss on securities, net",
    "27": "Retirement of shares",
    "28": "Conversion of Series AA convertible preferred stock",
    "29": "Balance at June 30, 2015"
  },
  "3": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Shares",
    "6": "626,667",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "400,000",
    "20": "1,026,667",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "-400000",
    "29": "626,667"
  },
  "7": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "Series B and Series AA",
    "4": "Pref Stock",
    "5": "Amount",
    "6": "626",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "400",
    "20": "1,026",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "-400",
    "29": "626"
  },
  "11": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Shares",
    "6": "1,028,743",
    "7": "",
    "8": "62,500",
    "9": "42,500",
    "10": "27,169",
    "11": "-40000",
    "12": "",
    "13": "18,513",
    "14": "",
    "15": "57,635",
    "16": "527,666",
    "17": "18,214",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "1,742,940",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "6,903,286",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "-5976",
    "28": "903,825,954",
    "29": "912,466,204"
  },
  "15": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "Common Stock",
    "5": "Amount",
    "6": "1,027",
    "7": "",
    "8": "63",
    "9": "43",
    "10": "27",
    "11": "-40",
    "12": "",
    "13": "19",
    "14": "",
    "15": "58",
    "16": "528",
    "17": "18",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "1,743",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "6,903",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "-6",
    "28": "903,826",
    "29": "912,466"
  },
  "19": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "Accumulated Other",
    "4": "Comprehensive",
    "5": "Loss",
    "6": "-80180",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "-817",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-80997",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "-1",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-80998"
  },
  "23": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "Additional",
    "4": "Paid-In",
    "5": "Capital",
    "6": "47,642,898",
    "7": "",
    "8": "271,105",
    "9": "218,957",
    "10": "169,973",
    "11": "-527960",
    "12": "",
    "13": "104,481",
    "14": "194,531",
    "15": "564,667",
    "16": "321,338",
    "17": "-18",
    "18": "",
    "19": "115,687",
    "20": "49,075,659",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "49,660",
    "24": "282,470",
    "25": "480,317",
    "26": "",
    "27": "6",
    "28": "-903426",
    "29": "48,984,686"
  },
  "27": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "Accumulated",
    "5": "Deficit",
    "6": "-47921946",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "-4894278",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-52816224",
    "21": "",
    "22": "-1880667",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-54696891"
  },
  "31": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Share",
    "6": "-406",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-406",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-406"
  },
  "35": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "Treasury Stock",
    "5": "Amount",
    "6": "-13000",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-13000",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-13000"
  },
  "39": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Total",
    "6": "-370575",
    "7": "",
    "8": "271,168",
    "9": "219,000",
    "10": "170,000",
    "11": "-528000",
    "12": "-4894278",
    "13": "104,500",
    "14": "194,531",
    "15": "564,725",
    "16": "321,866",
    "17": "-",
    "18": "-817",
    "19": "116,087",
    "20": "-3831793",
    "21": "",
    "22": "-1880667",
    "23": "49,660",
    "24": "289,373",
    "25": "480,317",
    "26": "-1",
    "27": "-",
    "28": "-",
    "29": "-4893111"
  }
}
```

Comment: See - https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like below [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1r5obvf/)

in template

```
<div style="clear: both;" *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(data)">
             <h2>{{key}}</h2>
             <div style="clear: both;" *ngFor="let sKey of objectKeys(data[key])">
                <b>{{sKey}}</b> : {{data[key][sKey]}}
             </div>
          </div>
```

in component

```
public objectKeys = Object.keys;
      public data: any = {} // your data
```

//Full source

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
      <div style="clear: both;" *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(data)">
         <h2>{{key}}</h2>
         <div style="clear: both;" *ngFor="let sKey of objectKeys(data[key])">
            <b>{{sKey}}</b> : {{data[key][sKey]}}
         </div>
      </div>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  public objectKeys = Object.keys;
  public data: any = {
  "0": {
    "0": null,
    "1": "Consolidated Statements of Changes in Stockholders\u2019 Deficit",
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "",
    "6": "Balance at September 30, 2013",
    "7": "",
    "8": "Common stock issued for exercise of options",
    "9": "Common stock issued for services",
    "10": "Common stock issued to employees",
    "11": "Common stock returned by employees",
    "12": "Net loss for the nine months",
    "13": "Shares issued as finance fee",
    "14": "Amortization of deferred compensation",
    "15": "Common stock issued for acquisition",
    "16": "Payment on convertible note",
    "17": "Exercise of common stock warrants",
    "18": "Unrealized loss on securities, net",
    "19": "Preferred stock",
    "20": "Balance at June 30, 2014",
    "21": "",
    "22": "Net loss for the year",
    "23": "Amortization of deferred compensation",
    "24": "Shares issued for conversion of notes payable",
    "25": "Write-off of derivative liability upon conversion",
    "26": "Unrealized loss on securities, net",
    "27": "Retirement of shares",
    "28": "Conversion of Series AA convertible preferred stock",
    "29": "Balance at June 30, 2015"
  },
  "3": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Shares",
    "6": "626,667",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "400,000",
    "20": "1,026,667",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "-400000",
    "29": "626,667"
  },
  "7": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "Series B and Series AA",
    "4": "Pref Stock",
    "5": "Amount",
    "6": "626",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "400",
    "20": "1,026",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "-400",
    "29": "626"
  },
  "11": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Shares",
    "6": "1,028,743",
    "7": "",
    "8": "62,500",
    "9": "42,500",
    "10": "27,169",
    "11": "-40000",
    "12": "",
    "13": "18,513",
    "14": "",
    "15": "57,635",
    "16": "527,666",
    "17": "18,214",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "1,742,940",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "6,903,286",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "-5976",
    "28": "903,825,954",
    "29": "912,466,204"
  },
  "15": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "Common Stock",
    "5": "Amount",
    "6": "1,027",
    "7": "",
    "8": "63",
    "9": "43",
    "10": "27",
    "11": "-40",
    "12": "",
    "13": "19",
    "14": "",
    "15": "58",
    "16": "528",
    "17": "18",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "1,743",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "6,903",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "-6",
    "28": "903,826",
    "29": "912,466"
  },
  "19": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "Accumulated Other",
    "4": "Comprehensive",
    "5": "Loss",
    "6": "-80180",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "-817",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-80997",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "-1",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-80998"
  },
  "23": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "Additional",
    "4": "Paid-In",
    "5": "Capital",
    "6": "47,642,898",
    "7": "",
    "8": "271,105",
    "9": "218,957",
    "10": "169,973",
    "11": "-527960",
    "12": "",
    "13": "104,481",
    "14": "194,531",
    "15": "564,667",
    "16": "321,338",
    "17": "-18",
    "18": "",
    "19": "115,687",
    "20": "49,075,659",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "49,660",
    "24": "282,470",
    "25": "480,317",
    "26": "",
    "27": "6",
    "28": "-903426",
    "29": "48,984,686"
  },
  "27": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "Accumulated",
    "5": "Deficit",
    "6": "-47921946",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "-4894278",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-52816224",
    "21": "",
    "22": "-1880667",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-54696891"
  },
  "31": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Share",
    "6": "-406",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-406",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-406"
  },
  "35": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "Treasury Stock",
    "5": "Amount",
    "6": "-13000",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": "",
    "12": "",
    "13": "",
    "14": "",
    "15": "",
    "16": "",
    "17": "",
    "18": "",
    "19": "",
    "20": "-13000",
    "21": "",
    "22": "",
    "23": "",
    "24": "",
    "25": "",
    "26": "",
    "27": "",
    "28": "",
    "29": "-13000"
  },
  "39": {
    "0": null,
    "1": null,
    "2": null,
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "Total",
    "6": "-370575",
    "7": "",
    "8": "271,168",
    "9": "219,000",
    "10": "170,000",
    "11": "-528000",
    "12": "-4894278",
    "13": "104,500",
    "14": "194,531",
    "15": "564,725",
    "16": "321,866",
    "17": "-",
    "18": "-817",
    "19": "116,087",
    "20": "-3831793",
    "21": "",
    "22": "-1880667",
    "23": "49,660",
    "24": "289,373",
    "25": "480,317",
    "26": "-1",
    "27": "-",
    "28": "-",
    "29": "-4893111"
  }
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have object inside object so need to run for loop twice as below.

```
 <div *ngFor="let items of testObject | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{items.key}}</b> 
       <div *ngFor="let item of items | key">
             value:<b>{{item.value}}</b>
       </div>
   <hr>
 </div>
```